# Is there such a connection on the punctured plane?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Is  there a  connection on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ for  which  all  operators of  parallel transports are in the  form $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a \end{pmatrix}$$

but the parallel transport along  circles with  center at origin depends  on the  radius of the  circle. That is  two  different  circle  have  different  parallel transports.

This  question is    motivated  by [this  paper](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/43009/1995-47.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Take the Levi-Civita connection of any conformal metric $g = e^{2u}(dx^2+dy^2)$ of positive curvature, say.  Then, by (local) Gauss-Bonnet, the holonomy around any smooth closed loop $\gamma$ is of the above form with $a = \cos\theta(\gamma)$ and $b=\sin\theta(\gamma)$, where
$$
\theta(\gamma) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}\,\gamma} \nu_\gamma\,K\,dA,
$$
where $\nu_{\gamma}:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}\,\gamma\to\mathbb{Z}$ gives the winding number of $\gamma$ about the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that do not lie on the image of $\gamma$.  When $\gamma_r$ is the circle $(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$ for $r>0$, $\theta(\gamma_r)$ is just the total curvature of the metric contained in the interior of the disk.  Since $K>0$, this number increases as $r$ increases.